# How to remove element from HTML string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't seem to be working, I get an `Uncaught Type` error on the `.remove()` line:

JS:

```
var str = $("a").html();
var $html = $.parseHTML(str);
$("i",$html).remove();  

$("div").html($html);
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Hello <i>Bob</i></a>
<div></div>
```

How to get this to work?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Seems simple but make sure your jQuery library is imported correctly. I usually get a similar error if my reference to jQuery is off.

Comment: @DeFeNdog Remove the `<i>` from the `<a>`, pretty straight-forward

Comment: Why not just do $("a i").remove(); ?

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the link on the page or from a "copy" of the html?

Comment: @VictorioBerra That would remove it from the object, I need to extract it as a string first, without conflicting with the object

Comment: `var clone = $("selector").clone();
clone.find("i").remove();`

Comment: Seems like people are having trouble understanding the question, please see the edit on usage of the variable

Comment: Sorry, but your edit still doesn't make sense.  Please explain in detail what you have, and what your intended results are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone `a`, change html code of clone and put clone inside `div`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vo22c6ya/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var clone = $("a").clone();
    clone.find("i").remove();
    $("div").html(clone);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the HTML tags by just using the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

```
var str = $("a").text();

$("a").text(str);
```

Which will result in:

```
<a href="#">Hello Bob</a>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3s1c55w2/

How it works:

1. The `$("a").text();` will retrieve only the text of the element, so in your case it will return `Hello Bob`.
2. Once you retrieve `Hello Bob`, simply set the `a` tags text value using `.text(str)` again, where the `str` is the value with no html tags.

Comment: Seems like people are having trouble understanding the question, please see the edit on usage of the variable

Comment: The jsFiddle I've provided clearly shows that it does.  I would check to see if your jQuery implementation is setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he's trying to remove i tags from every anchor.

http://jsfiddle.net/1fytum86/

```
$("a").each(function(index) {
    var str = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(str);
});
```

Anyway, it's possible that he was getting a type error because parseHTML() parses a string into an array of DOM nodes. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the italics and leave the text:

```
$("a").html($("a").html().replace(/<\/?i>/g, ""));
```

Otherwise, the other answers using either remove or detach would be appropriate.